# How to set Echo on/off for file manipulation

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, operating-system

I have an issue with `echo` on/off on blank rows. I have tried multiple things, including `echo` variable among other things.

Here is the code I currently am using along with the log and the current output after I use the script to parse records with some records being blank that I want to have remain blank.

**Current Code**

```
for /f "skip=%skipTo% tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a In ('type %InputFile% ^| find /v /n ""') do (
    set ip=%%b
    set ip=!ip:!
    set test=!ip!
    echo !ip!
    echo(!test!

    if "!test!" == [] (
        !test! >> E:\EPM_Cloud\LoadFiles\BUD_PLN\Security\GROUPS_USERS_CURRENT_LIST.csv
    ) else (echo %%b >> E:\EPM_Cloud\LoadFiles\BUD_PLN\Security\GROUPS_USERS_CURRENT_LIST.csv)
)
```

**Current Output** (Note that I need to retain the 3 blank lines that currently have "ECHO is off")

```
#group_children 
id,group_id,group_provider,user_id,user_provider 
BL_LEAD,,,TestUser_2,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
BL_LEAD,,,angelo.vergura@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
 ECHO is off.
#group_children 
id,group_id,group_provider,user_id,user_provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,Christopher.George@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,Lindsey.Heeszel@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,Safa.Kaleem@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,Susan.Orbach@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,Tung.Truong@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,angelo.vergura@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,arodriguez,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,camason@huronconsultinggroup.com,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,jeffrey.sheldon@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,larry.mason@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,mary.moshier@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
NON_BL_LEAD,,,sreekanth.manne@nrc.gov,LDAP_Directory_Provider 
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

**Current Log** -  After Execution for this code (as you can see this is evidence of why I am getting it in the output for a blank line? When there isn't a blank line you get the results but they aren't showing in the log

```
ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.

ECHO is off.
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Grab a certain piece of text in the csv or just remove blank lines?

Comment: If a variable echoed evaluates to nothing you can use a different command seperator than tthe usual space. There are several possible chars which all have the one or otther disadvantage. My prefernce is the colon. `echo:%variable%` this avoids the echo status being output.

Comment: There is no such command as `/v /n ""') do (`, I have no idea what `set ip=!ip:!` is supposed to do, `"!test!"` can never be equal to `[]` as one of them always has doublequotes and the other never has doublequotes. Is `!test!` supposed to resolve to a command, or are you missing maybe an `Echo`? As for you `Echo` issue, you could replace `echo !ip!` with `echo(!ip!`, `echo=!ip!` or `echo/!ip!`.

Comment: Hi All, yeah just trying to keep the blank lines from a csv flat file - but when I grab them as well as the lines that are not blank - the blanks come back as "echo is off"

Comment: Why did you start another question?

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the ECHO IS OFF (or ON) message when the line is empty (or nothing but whitespace), then simply use `ECHO(%%b` instead of `ECHO %%b`.

Traditionally people used `ECHO.` to eliminate problems with blank lines. But there are some obscure situations where that can cause problems.

`ECHO(` always works.

Answer (score 0):

`if "!test!" == []` will NEVER match. Don't use spaces.

`If "%string%"==""` does something if string is blank.

Comment: spaces are not a problem in this case, but the rest of your answer is valid

Comment: @dbenham It was pre-emptive. I have a general principal of NEVER using spaces in an `if` statement. Go do a data analysis on how many `if` questions have been posted here with errant spaces as the issue.